# Codeigniter Session logged in customer to admin login

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, logging

I Developed E-eCommerce Website in Codeigniter but I have one main problem.

In this site if I'm logged in the admin panel and don't log out from admin panel and then try to log into customer panel then it will automatically redirect to admin panel, even though I'm logged into customer panel.

You can test online: http://a2zshopping.my-board.org/?i=1 admin panel link is http://a2zshopping.my-board.org/admin.

Admin email: admin@gmail.com
Password: admin
Customer: ali@gmail.com
Pass: c%$#@!

Below is my code in controller/login class

```
//admin login
  public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        if($this->session->userdata('admin_email'))
        {
            return redirect("admin");
        }


    }

    public function doLogin()
    {
        $post=$this->input->post();
        $this->load->model("Authentication","au");
        $data=$this->au->doLogin($post);
        if($data)
        {
            $this->session->set_userdata("admin_email",$data);
            return redirect("admin");
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("failed","Email and Password is not correct");
            return redirect("login");
        }

    }
    //customer login
    public function do_c_Login()
    {
        $post=$this->input->post();
        $this->load->model("Authentication","au");
        $data=$this->au->do_c_Login($post);
        if($data)
        {
            $c_email=$data->c_email;
            $c_id=$data->c_id;
            $this->session->set_userdata("c_email",$c_email);
            $this->session->set_userdata("c_id",$c_id);
            return redirect("shop/profile");
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata([
                "msg"=>"Email and Password do match",
                "class"=>"danger",
                "heading"=>"ERROR"
                ]);
            return redirect("shop/login");
        }

    }
```

And this is code in controller/admin

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        if(!$this->session->userdata('admin_email'))
        {
            return redirect("login");
        }
        $this->load->model("Order_management","om");
        $this->load->model("user_management","um");
        $this->load->model("inventory_management","im");

    }
```

Below is code in shop/login for customer

```
if(!$this->session->userdata('c_email'))
        {
            return redirect("shop/login");
        }
```

Comment: Of course this will happen. You have a check to see if an admin email address is set in the persistent userdata ('admin_email'). Until this is cleared, they will always be redirected to admin area until you clear this userdata, but then they're not authorised as admin. You should not do forced redirects like this. You should separate the controller into two controllers: one for customer and one for admin which extend a base controller.

Comment: Please explain more how to fix this, But email addresses that's store in Session Variable is different then why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

of course it happen,because you set  `admin@gmail.com` in `SESSION` and when you leave admin panel,it is still in `SESSION`

Comment: But email addresses that's store in Session Variable is different then why ?

Comment: yes,but you check session in constract function,when each time use this controller,redirect you to admin page

Comment: in admin panel i checked in construct fucntion but in shop class there are many other function which may not require the login session.

Comment: then what will be the best solution to fix it?

Comment: Its depend on your code design, mostly all admin code is in the same controller you need to redesign your code otherwise you should define global function for check session and use it at the first of each function